# PyWebIO: Can't set vertical position of pinned input

Tags: python, css, css-position

I'm making an application in PyWebIO, and want to have a search bar, so I'm using `put_input`
I want to center the input both vertically and horizontally on the page.

I tried to use `put_column`, but it didn't move my input at all. I am trying to use the `style` function now, but using relative positioning, I can move my input horizontally but not vertically.

```
from pywebio.input import *
from pywebio.pin import *
from pywebio.output import *
from pywebio.session import *
from download import *
from pywebio import start_server

def test():
    style(put_input(name="Date2",type=DATE),"position: relative; top: 50%;")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_server(test,port=443)
```

This just leaves the input at the top.
Changing it to `left: 50%;` results in this:
[image: input field moved to the right]